# JMeter with Elasticsearch as data source

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, jmeter, load-testing, packetbeat

I am capturing http traffic using **Packetbeat**. The captured traffic is stored in **Elasticsearch** and consists of SOAP requests (including request body, headers etc). In total I have about 500 million requests in the database at any given time.

My goal is to replay a specific timespan worth of requests (~ 30 million requests) using **JMeter**. I would like to use something like the Throughput Shaping Timer (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/). So far I have no good idea how to get the data into a JMeter test plan. Any suggestions?

The standard csv approach seems subpar because: 
 1. Generating a csv-File containing 30 million requests including the request body seems shitty considering I already have the requests in a database 
2. The timespan from which I select requests will change consistently. So I would have to generate lots of csv-Files

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for that much record set you need to create the data source of millions of record set and csv is the best option. I have created so many test plans in my career and found csv data source is quite significant. I would recommend to use csv for manipulating in your elastic search.